# Google script Execution API authentication using Google script to make the call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to make an API call from a google script to another script file. I published the script I am trying to call as an API. Then tried to make a call.

```
  var scriptID = 'Script key given by google'
  var request = {
    'funciton':'ClearALL',
  }
  var header = {
    'method':'POST',
    'body':request,
  }
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + scriptID + ':run', header)
```

I received this error:

```
{ "code": 401, "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }
```

So, it seems to me that it is because I am not authorized to make the call to my script.

My question is, how do I send a request for authentication to my script, in google app script? I have fond how to do it in javascript [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample), but I really don't know how to do it with google script's `urlFetch`.

Comment: check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752032/passing-authentication-from-one-google-apps-script-webapp-to-another-google-apps), check Zig Mandel and kiwidrew both gave some good points and guides on how to implement of the workaround. I hope it helps.